# Pulling author name via $_GET parameter

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, author

So I'm running a few ACF forms. One creates the post, and then I have an edit post form that edits the post via a form that populates based on the post id.

So my edit post url: site.com/edit-post/?post=478

Then I have some code in my file:

```
    <?php 

        $post_id = $_GET["post"];
```

This effectively lets me get the current post ID based on the ID passed in the URL. It works well for my forms.
The issue I'm having is I want to display the author name for the post in the URL, however I can't seem to find the right syntax to do it.
I've tried `the_author();` and it doesn't give me the right author.

Additionally, I tried `the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post_id['post_author'] );` and it gave me a different author name but still not the right author for the post.

Any ideas as to what I could try to get this working?

Thanks, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: if `$post_id` is the ID, then you should pass `$post_id`, not `$post_id['post_author']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the author ID of the post ID via [get_post_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field)

```
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

With this post ID you get all author meta data, also the name like

```
the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post_author_id );
```